# How do I solve this equation for $t$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

$$ \frac{48}{4^{-t}+2} = 0 $$

Apparently, when I graph it, it has a horizontal asymptote at $0$. How do I find the solution?

Thank you

Comment: How is this an equation?

Comment: i can't see any equation

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post.

Comment: You can't find it. You end up dividing by zero.

Comment: There is no real number that when you divide 48 by it, you get 0.

Comment: What is the difficulty? If $t$ becomes large and positive then the denominator approaches 2, so we the graph approaches the line $y=24$ from below. If $t$ becomes large and negative, then $4^{-t}$ becomes large and positive, so the graph approaches the line $y=0$ from above.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas because it has an equals sign $=$.... I’m just trolling hahah. Look, David, you can’t graph this because *how can a fraction* $= 0$?

Comment: @user477343 Well (x/1000) = 0 is possible because x could be 0. So fraction = 0 is possible right

Comment: @David ok, my mistake. But if $x = 48$, then how can this equal $0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Analysing the expression

$$\frac{48}{4^{-t}+2}$$

the most we can have is make $t\to -\infty$ and then we get

$$\frac{48}{4^{-t}+2}\to 0$$

but we will never reach $0$.